# Go: mock return value of a function in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, stub

I have created a small script in golang (my first golang project).

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    i := rand.Intn(10)
    foo := foo(i)

    if foo {
        fmt.Printf("%d is even!", i)
        // more code ... 
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%d is odd!", i)
        // more code ... 
    }
}

func foo(i int) bool {
    if i%2 == 0 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I would like to create a small unit test for each function.
For "main()", I want to mock the return value of function "foo()", because I won't test "foo()", but the rest of main()-code.

I'm looking for an easy way to stub/mock the return value.
I just found mocks with struct or interaces etc. But I didn't use these elements in code (it's a simple project).

Comment: You're thinking like a Pythonista, not a Gopher. In go you wouldn't redefine foo as a mock.  " because I won't test "foo()", but the rest of main()-code" then put the rest of `main`'s code in another function and test *that*.  You can't test `main` with go tests anyhow.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thx for confirmaton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a realistic, minimal, reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

For example, in Go,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func isEven(i int) bool {
    return i%2 == 0
}

func side(n int) string {
    if isEven(n) {
        return "right"
    } else {
        return "left"
    }
}

func main() {
    n := 1 + rand.Intn(10)
    hand := side(n)
    fmt.Printf("Number %d is on the %s-hand side of the street.\n", n, hand)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/a0SudgaRCnu

```
Number 9 is on the left-hand side of the street.
```

---

Use the Go [testing package](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) to unit test the `side` function. You might also unit test the `isEven` function directly. The `main` function should not contain any code that you want to unit test.

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSide(t *testing.T) {
    n := 7
    got := side(n)
    want := "left"
    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("side(%d) = %s; want %s", n, got, want)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanition. This confirms my assumption.
I will refactor the code and outsource rest of `main`.